# Monolithic -> SOA. Advice needed

Tags: soa

I have few questions regarding the best practices for the SOA/microservice architecture.
We currently have monolithic application, but we would like to start dividing it into services.

So, here is a problem:
Lets say I have a user. User might have multiple topics. User might add/upload documents to the topics.
We would like to create a separate service for the Documents.

So it would look like:

```
User/Client -- requests --> Frontend/Main-monolithic Service -- requests --> Documents Service
```

When User/Client uploads a Document he specifies a topic to which the Document should be uploaded.
The data about which topic belongs to which user/client is located in Frontend/Main-monolithic service ( well, in the database of this service ).

Question:
There should "access-control" checks located?
In other words, where should be checked, if user can upload a document to the specified topic ( or if the topic belongs to this user )?

I see three options:

- The check will be in Frontned/Main-monolithic Service and then this service will invoke Documents Service.
  So Documents Service ***trusts*** the Frontend/Main-monolithic.
- The check will be in Documents Service through the service call, but it will currently introduce a circular dependency:

  `User/Client -- requests --> Frontend/Main-monolithic Service -- requests --> Documents Service -- requests --> Frontend/Main-monolithic Service`
- Create multiple services so this would be something like:

  `User/Client -- requests --> Frontend Service -- requests --> Documents Service -- requests --> Topic Service`

But as you can imagine, it's a bit risky to start splitting the production monolithic application in lots of services at once.
We would like to mitigate the risk and decrease the probability of the errors as much as possible. So from our point of view introducing services one by one might decrease the risk.

Any help/advice/suggestions would be highly appreciated!
Thank you in advance.

Best Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As with every SOA-topic this is a matter of taste. I would go with the third scenario, but do it step by step. Extract the assignment between user and topic into something like a TopicAuthorizationService as the first step. This service can be called by your monolith. Test this little refactoring.

```
Frontend/Main-monolithic Service -- requests --> TopicAuthorizationService 
Frontend/Main-monolithic Service -- writesDocument--> Filesystem/DB whatever
```

As a next step extract the DocumentService and leave the call to the TopicAuthorizationService in you monolith. Again: test this refactoring

```
Frontend/Main-monolithic Service -- requests --> TopicAuthorizationService 
Frontend/Main-monolithic Service -- requests --> DocumentService 
DocumentService -- writesDocument--> Filesystem/DB whatever
```

Third step: move the authorization call to the DocumentService. Test it.

```
Frontend/Main-monolithic Service -- requests --> DocumentService
DocumentService -- requests --> TopicAuthorizationService 
DocumentService -- writesDocument--> Filesystem/DB whatever
```

This way you can lower the impact and ensure production.

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what we think would be better.
So, we anyway start with "DocumentService" trusts "Frontend/Main-monolithic" ( at least in the beginning ).

Answer (score 0):

Its not just about the complexity of the services themselves, but the guys implementing, orchestrating and managing them. 
Introducing SOA means foremost adding a massive overhead in human communication to get things done. 
In case you and your team have this one under control, this is definitely the way to go.